# QT Request to SaleForse with status code 0

Tags: qt, http, post, salesforce, http-post

I have a standalone app that has a function with 2 post request functions, first to get token from salesforse, second to send my json data, when i execute app on my computer its sending request just fine, but on other computers status code from the post request is 0. There is no code description, just nothing.
Why it behave like this, and how to maybe understand what is the problem(like error description).

FIRST ONE:

```
void Connector::SendFirstPostRequest()
    {
            //QNetworkAccessManager *NetManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
            QNetworkAccessManager NetManager;
            QUrlQuery postData;
            QObject Connector;
            QString FURL = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token";
            QUrl URLNeeded(FURL);
QNetworkRequest request(URLNeeded);
        request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,QVariant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

        QNetworkReply *reply = NetManager.post(request, postD.toString(QUrl::FullyEncoded).toUtf8());
while (!reply->isFinished())
        {
            qApp->processEvents();

        }
        FirstPostFinished = reply->isFinished();

        QByteArray ResponceData = reply->readAll();
        QJsonDocument rDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(ResponceData);
        QJsonObject rJObject = rDoc.object();
        QJsonValue AccessToke = rJObject.value("access_token");
        AcessToken = AccessToke.toString();
        FirstPostCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();

        qDebug() << "STATUS: "<< FirstPostCode;
//        qDebug() << reply->header();
        qDebug() << "POST REQUEST SENT";

        reply->deleteLater();
}
```

SECOND:

```
void Connector::SendSecondPostRequest()
{
        QNetworkAccessManager NetManager;
        QUrlQuery postData;
        QObject Connector;
        QUrl URLNeeded(URL);
        

        QJsonObject json;
        QJsonDocument doc(json);
       
        QNetworkRequest request(URLNeeded);
        request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/json");
        auto header = QString("Bearer %1").arg(AcessToken);
        request.setRawHeader(QByteArray("Authorization"), header.toUtf8());

        QNetworkReply *reply = NetManager.post(request, doc.toJson());
        qDebug()<<doc;

        while (!reply->isFinished())
        {
            qApp->processEvents();

        }

        QByteArray ResponceData = reply->readAll();
        QJsonDocument jDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(ResponceData);
        qDebug() << jDoc;
        DebugLine = QString(jDoc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact));

        SecPostCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();

        qDebug() << "STATUS: "<<SecPostCode;
        qDebug() << "POST REQUEST SENT";

        reply->deleteLater();
}
```

AND THE FUNCTION THAT OPERATE THIS TWO REQUESTS

```
void MainWindow::SendPost()
{
    if(Conn->SecondsToRequest == 10)
    {
       Conn->SendFirstPostRequest();
       
       while(!Conn->FirstPostFinished)
       {
          qDebug()<<"First post not finished yet";
       }
       Conn->SendSecondPostRequest();
       Conn->SecondsToRequest = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `while (!reply->isFinished())` instead of connecting to the `finished` signal?

Comment: what's the URL in the second call? You're supposed to read the access token and instance url from the login's response (see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5) and then use that as baseline for all subsequent calls. Construct something like `{instance_url}/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Account` and then you POST the JSON of the account you want to create.

Comment: @eyescream Yeah second post request is posted with other url, and its working on my PC (all data received on SalesForce) but on other PC i getting this 0 respoce code

Comment: @JarMan I am using while (!reply->isFinished()) because 2 post request methods in one class Connector, and SendPost method in MainWindow so i cant connect to reply->isFinished()  from FirstPostRequest to Second

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense. Why does it matter that you are making 2 post requests in one class? You can still use connect().

Comment: @JarMan The main thing that app is working, on my and my collegue PC (he dont have qt creator), but on everyone else PC its returning status code 0. But can you plese little bit explain how to connect 2 requests but i need to perform some preparations in between. Thank you in advance

Comment: Gotta love "works on my machine" errors. Salesforce wouldn't even return "0", it'd be a proper HTTP code like 400,500,503... Something with code or network. Any chance you have firewall config or proxy that'd be different on your colleague's machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all, i use Qt MessageHandler to write log file, and there was an TLS initialization failed, so the problem solved with installing OpenSSL 1.1.1h and Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it but how did it manage to make first call (login) over https but not the 2nd one? Crazy.

Comment: @eyescream Actually, at first attemp i made debug label where i set only status code, only from second request so it confused me, and later when i write log i saw that they are both failed.

Comment: Got it :) Thx for coming back to me, it'd bug me at night :)

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered status code 0 issue and it was due to request time out.
If you are getting status code 0 then try increasing timeout of your request.